# Why does Coriolis force act on North-South moving air?

Tags: coriolis-effect

Earth's axis is North-South; then why does air moving towards or away from North or South experience Coriolis force, since $\vec\omega\times \vec v$ will be 0 in this case?

Comment: Because "north/south" is a different direction depending on where you are? If you're looking at a globe, 'north' at the equator points up to the ceiling. But north near the north pole is almost horizontal.

Comment: To elaborate:  $\vec{\omega}$ points towards the [North Celestial Pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_pole), **not** north along the Earth's surface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Earth is spherical. So at non-zero latitudes, north-south direction is not parallel to the rotational axis. At equator, it's parallel, and you are right that at the equator, there is no Coriolis force acting on north-south moving objects.